# Store everything after a match in Array List in a String

Tags: java

I have a Method which gets a File with a path for a txt file as argument. A buffered reader reads some lines into a arraylist. So far so good but now i need to store every element after specific element in a String.

Example: I have a element in this array list which is '=' after i hit this element I want to store every element after this element into a String.

I played around with loops and if statements but could not find a solution.

```
    //Just for debugging purpose at some point i want to store a temperature in here and return it to Main
    int temp = 1;

    List<String> sensor_Daten = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new   FileReader(path));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sensor_Daten.add(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException IOEx)
    {

    }

    return temp;
```

Comment: Store how?  Can you give an example input and desired output?

Comment: I've removed the IntelliJ and RPi tags since they're not relevant. This comment is also unrelated, but I'd recommend doing something lighter-weight than Java for pretty much anything on the RPi, especially if it's something trivial as this appears to be (without context).

Comment: Input: 9e 01 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 8a : crc=8a YES
9e 01 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 8a t=25875 Output: 25875

Comment: Please don't elaborate on your question by commenting on it.  Instead, [edit] your question to add any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be too hard :

```
BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new   FileReader(path));
String line;
boolean isWordFound = false;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)        {  

    // add the line in the list if the word was found       
    if (isWordFound()){
      sensor_Daten.add(line);
    }

    // flag isWordFound to true when the match is done the first time
    if (!isWordFound && line.matches(myRegex)){
      isWordFound = true;
    } 
}
```

As a side note you don't close the stream while you should do it. 
The `try-with-resource` statement does that for you. So you should favor this way.
Broadly that :

```
BufferedReader reader = ...;
try{
    reader =  new BufferedReader(new   FileReader(path));
}
finally{
  try{
    reader.close();
   }
  catch(IOException e) {...}
}
```

should be just :

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))){
    ...
}
```